# how to get 1 hidden field among several within div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 3 hidden fields in 1 div. when I have reference to this div, how to get 1 of the  hidden fields in this div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will also work (jQuery):

```
$('#my_div').find('input[type=hidden]:first')
```

Comment: $('#my_div').find('input[type="hidden"]:first')

Watch the quotes.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a DIV, like so:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <input type="hidden">
    <input type="hidden">
    <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

You can use jQuery to do something like this to select all of them:

```
$('input:hidden','#mydiv');
```

With that selector, now you have all 3 hidden fields in a jQuery collection. You can pick and choose from there which one you want to use by using several methods:

```
$('input:hidden:first','#mydiv'); // get first one using first
$('input:hidden:last','#mydiv'); // get last one using last
$('input:hidden','#mydiv').eq(0); // get first one using eq
$('input:hidden','#mydiv').eq(1); // get second one using eq
$('input:hidden','#mydiv').eq(2); // get third one using eq
$('input:hidden:eq(0)','#mydiv'); // get first one using eq in selector
```

The options are:

- [`first`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first) - get the first matched element in the collection.
- [`last`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/last) - get the last matched element in the collection.
- [`eq(N)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq#index) - get the Nth matched element, 0 based.
- [`:eq(N)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index) - get the Nth matched element, 0 based, inside the selector string.

I am personally a fan of option 3 as I don't like having too much crap in my selector.

One caveat of the above is that by using the `:hidden` selector we might match other input elements that are hidden (ie, not visible). If you expect that to happen, or even if you don't, you could do this:

```
$('input[type=hidden]', '#mydiv').eq(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Without any code it's hard to help but i'd say give the hidden field an ID and use:

```
var hdn = document.getElementById("id");
```

Or if you're using Jquery use:

```
var hdn = $("#id");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstHidden = $("input[type='hidden']:first", ref);
```

[:first pseudo-class](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first) and [attribute selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue)

or

```
var firstHidden = $("input:hidden:first", ref);
```

[:hidden pseudo-class](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/hidden) (be careful, because :hidden finds also elements with style="display: none")

or

```
var firstHidden = $("input[type='hidden']", ref).eq(0);
```

[.eq()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq#index)

where 'ref' variable is a reference to the DIV element

Answer (score 1):

if it's like this:

```
<div id="somediv">
    <input type="hidden"/>
    <input type="hidden"/>
    <input type="hidden"/>
</div>
```

and you're using jquery, you can just write this:

```
$("#somediv > input[type='hidden']:eq(1)")
```

and it should return a reference to the 1st hidden field.  if you want the 2nd, use "eq(2)" and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I would assign a class to the hidden you want to find - a little easier on the programmer looking back on it in 4 years.  I'm using "id" as an example of the hidden.  Once you find it with jQuery - you can use .val() to get its value.

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <input type='hidden' name='mydiv_id' class='idField' value='test1' />
  <input type='hidden' name='mydiv_hidden2' class='option2' value='test2' />
  <input type='hidden' name='mydiv_hidden3' class='option3' value='test3' />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
//execute on document ready:
$(function() {
  var div = $('#mydiv'); //some jquery/dom element "div"

  // use the jQuery selector with "div" as our context.
  var $hidden = $('input.idField', div);

  alert($hidden.val()); // should alert 'test1'
});
```

Comment: if "div" is a jquery object - div.find('.idField'); and $('.idField', div) will do the same thing - I wasn't sure if you had a jQuery element or a DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

For a reference, if you're not using jQuery like the original poster and assuming the structure above:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <input type="hidden">
  <input type="hidden">
  <input type="hidden">
</div>

var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var inputs = div.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  // Match your input with inputs[i].name, etc.
}
```